# SQL server Instance hanging randomly

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssis, sql-server-2014

I have a SQL Server agent job running every 5 minutes with SSIS package from SSIS Catalog, that package does:

1. DELETE all existing data ON OLTP_DB
2. Extract data from Production DB
3. DELETE all existing data on OLAP_DB and then
4. Extract data transformed from OLTP_DB into OLAP_DB ...

**PROBLEM**

That job I mentioned above is hanging randomly for some reason that I don't know,
I just realize using the activity monitor, every time it hangs it shows something like:

[image]

and if I try to run any query against that database it does not response just say executing.... and nothing happen until I stop the job.

The average running time for that job is 5 or 6 minutes, but when it hangs it can stay running for days if I don´t stop it. :(

**WHAT I HAVE DONE**

- Set delayValidation : True
- Improved my queries
- No transactions running
- No locking or blocking (I guess)
- Rebuild and organize index
- Ran `DBCC FREEPROCCACHE`
- Ran `DBCC FREESESSIONCACHE`
- ETC.....

My settings:

- Recovery Mode Simple
- SSIS OLE DB Destination 
   1-Keep Identity (checked)
   2-Keep Nulls (checked)
   3-Table lock (checked)
   4-Check constraints (unchecked)
   rows per batch (blank)
   Maximum insert commit size(2147483647)

**Note:**

I have another job running a ssis package as well (small) in the same instance but different databases and when the main ETL mentioned above hangs then this small one sometimes, that is why I think the problem is with the instance (I guess).

I'm open to provide more information as need it.

Any assistance or help would be really appreciated!

Comment: Have u checked `dbcc opentran` ?

Comment: Yes, and nothing running.

Comment: Please check any database back job in overrun status, and try to run this `SELECT * FROM dbo.sysprocesses WHERE blocked <> 0`, `SELECT r.session_id
 ,s.TEXT
 ,r.[status]
 ,r.blocking_session_id
 ,r.cpu_time
 ,r.total_elapsed_time
FROM sys.dm_exec_requests r
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sql_handle) AS s`

Comment: Try running [sp_whoisactive](http://whoisactive.com/) when your instance is hanging. It will show you blocked processes and open transactions... way easier than trying to trace. You say the job runs every 5 minutes but takes 6 minutes to complete. Is the job blocking itself?

Comment: It doesn't look like it's hanging randomly. If it's showing `CXPACKET` waits, that means its performing a big query that's executing in parallel (except not really, because most workers are blocked waiting for some sequential part to finish). Check `sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks`. There are various online resources to help with that, for example [this one](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/updated-sys-dm_os_waiting_tasks-script-2/).

Comment: Yes you are right @JeroenMostert but it hangs, and I just notice it does for specific object of the ssis package.

Comment: What you call a "hang" is what other people call "an injudicious use of server resources". A true hang would be a situation where SQL Server stops accepting requests altogether; that's generally a bug, detected by SQL Server itself and it produces an entry in the error log. What you've got is blocked or resource-intensive queries; there are ways to troubleshoot those.

Comment: Yes, that is true, so I tried using OPTION (MAXDOP ), but it didn´t work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Jeroen Mostert and @Danielle Paquette-Harvey Said, By doing right click using the activity monitor I could figure out that I had an object that was executing in parallel (for some reason in the past), to fix the problem I remove the parallel structure and put everything to run in one batch.
Now it is working like a charm!!

Before:
[image]

After:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As Joeren Mostert said, it's showing CXPACKET which means that it's executing some work in parallel. ([cxpacket](https://www.sqlskills.com/help/waits/cxpacket/))
It's also showing ASYNC_NETWORK_IO ([async_network_io](https://www.sqlskills.com/help/waits/async_network_io/)) which means it's also transfering data to the network. 
There could be many reasons. Just a few more hints:

- Have you checked if network connection is slow? 
- What is the size of the data being transfered vs the speed of the network? 
- Is there an antivirus running that could slow the data transfer? 

My guess is that there is lots of data to transfer and that it's taking a long time. I would think either I/O or network but since you have an asyn_network_io that takes most of the cumulative wait time, I would go for network.